# Establishing an inertial frame of reference by observing a closed mechanical system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

> Suppose one has a closed system of $N$ material points with known masses, $m_1 ,..., m_N$ . Also given are their coordinates as functions of time, ${\bf r}_1(t), ..., {\bf r}_N(t)$, in some laboratory frame of reference, not necessarily inertial. These material points interact only with each other, through known potentials, $U_{ij}=U_{ij}(|{\bf r}_i-{\bf r}_j|)$.
>
> In the framework of classical mechanics, find some inertial frame of reference, i.e. (i) the coordinates of its origin, ${\bf r}_0(t)$, and (ii) the coordinates of three coordinate axes vectors, ${\bf e}_1(t)$, ${\bf e}_2(t)$, ${\bf e}_3(t)$, in the laboratory frame of reference.

For the part (i), there is a trivial closed-form solution. The part (ii) can be reduced to a system of ordinary differential equations for ${\bf e}_1(t)$, ${\bf e}_2(t)$, ${\bf e}_3(t)$. For a sufficiently large number of material points, this system of ordinary differential equations is over-determined. But is there some closed-form solution of (ii)?

Comment: If the frame is not necessarily inertial, what does a potential mean?

Comment: @DvijMankad :  Thank you for asking to clarify. These are the potentials of the conservative interaction forces between the material points in the system. They do not account for inertial forces one has to introduce in the non-inertial frame of reference.  At any time, the components of the gradients of these potentials can be calculated in any, possibly non-inertial, system of coordinates, giving the forces of interaction between the points in the system.  For instance, those can be electrostatic or gravitational potentials.

Comment: This is phrased like a school assignment. If it is, then please add the homework-and-exercises tag.

Comment: @BenCrowell To address your concern, this question is not a school assignment.

Comment: @DvijMankad : Does my explanation above answer your question? If not, please clarify why are/were you concerned about the use of potential in the non-inertial frame of reference. The formulation of problem may be changed (in fact, generalized) by specifying the pair-wise forces (not necessarily conservative) of interaction between the points.  But I would also like to understand what motivated your question.

Comment: @AL1117 What motivated my question was that Newtonian mechanics is fundamentally tied to inertial frames. If you are working with a non-inertial frame, you need to specify how it relates to an inertial frame and only then you can translate the laws of mechanics from the inertial frame into this non-inertial frame.

Comment: @DvijMankad : Indeed, Newtonian mechanics claims that inertial frames of reference exist, such that in those inertial frames of reference the laws of motion take a simpler form (the 2nd Newton law of motion, without the need to introduce the inertial forces). This problem asks how such inertial frame of reference can be constructively established, for one simple, but general enough mechanical system.

Comment: @DvijMankad :  In fact, this given humankind has solved (albeit at a great cost) a particular case of this problem, by establishing that the frame of reference centered at the center of the Sun (the barycenter of the solar system, more precisely) and with its axes oriented by the faraway stars, is an inertial frame of reference, in which the motion of the celestial bodies of the solar system follow from the Newtonian laws of motion.

Comment: @DvijMankad : One other way to understand what motivates this problem is to consider a thought experiment, where the observer is confined inside a cubical room with no windows, and with this room moving (accelerating and rotating) in an arbitrary way. The observer is asked to build any devices they want and to use them to establish the inertial frame of reference.

Comment: (continued) The observer may, for instance, create 3 linear accelerometers to measure linear accelerations of the room along 3 arbitrary perpendicular axes, e.g. three edges of the cubical room sharing the same corner, and 3 gyroscopes rotating (with sufficiently high angular momentum) around 3 mutually perpendicular rigidly connected axes.

Comment: (continued )By integrating the readings of the linear accelerometers twice by time, the observer will find 3 Cartesian coordinates of the origin of the inertial frame of reference. Following that, the observer will orient the axes of the frame of reference along the directions pointed by the 3 gyroscopes. The result is the inertial frame of reference.

Comment: (continued) The creation of such linear accelerometers and gyroscopes can be viewed as a special case of the above problem, with some extra allowances. E.g. the linear accelerometer can be realized by connecting the Hookean spring (Uij = -k(xi-xj)^2) to the corner of the room and connecting the point mass to the loose end of this spring. The gyroscopes with a sufficiently high angular momentum can be built by rigidly connecting (Uij = \delta(|ri-rj|) ) two point masses to the axis of rotation (placed away from the axis), and giving these points sufficiently high initial momentums.

Comment: (continued) The original problem asks - how can the same (finding the inertial frame of reference) be done if these extra allowances allowing to build the linear accelerometers and gyroscopes (specific interaction potentials, ability to rigidly connect one of the mass points to the corner of the room, special initial conditions) are not available. The only system that is given is the large enough system of mass points interacting through the known potentials. Their observed trajectories should be sufficient to establish the inertial frame of reference.